# How to exclude content elements indexing via typo3 index search and crawler

Tags: indexing, typo3, web-crawler

When i crawled the content from Backend then i will index all the content .
I wanted to exclude perticular content area or ( perticular content elements ).

I am using typo3 version 4.7.12
and index search 4.7.7 and crawler version 3.5.0

Any ideas please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition you can insert markers as HTML comments which define which part of the body-text to include or exclude in the indexing:

The marker is `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` and/or `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->`

Rules:

- If there is no marker at all, everything is included.
- If the first found marker is an “end” marker, the previous content until that point is included and the preceeding code until next “begin” marker is excluded.
- If the first found marker is a “begin” marker, the previous content until that point is excluded and preceeding content until next “end” marker is included.

[Copy & pasted from documentation](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/doc_indexed_search/4.2.1/view/1/6/)

Comment: Hi Michael 
Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: I am indexing the content via backend.

Comment: I am indexing the content via backend . Front end indexing works fine. Because i have used Typo3 search begin and end.
but when i crawl via backend i will crawl all the data and no matter about the markers specified.